# Suppose $f^{\prime\prime}(y) < 0$ at a point $y$, when it is true that $f^{\prime\prime}(z) < 0$ for all $z$ in an interval around $y$?

Tags: calculus, analysis, derivatives

Consider some function $f: \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$. Suppose I computed the second derivative of $f$ and then proceeded to evaluate at a point $y$, in which I found,

$$f^{\prime\prime}(y) < 0$$

When it is true that  $f^{\prime\prime}(z) < 0$ for all $z$ in an interval around $y$?

I am thinking of a $\cap$ looking function. If $f^{\prime\prime}$ is continuous and differentiable everywhere, then I can move some epsilon distance away from that point $y$ and the concavity condition still holds, is this right?

Are there any other conditions (possibly more relaxed than continuous differentiability of the second derivative) such that this holds.

Comment: Do you assume $f''$ exists on an interval around $y$?  If not, your counterexample is easy.

Comment: There is no need that $f''$ is differentiable, continuous is enough.

Comment: When $f''(x)<0$ in a domain D, then $f(x)$ can hold at most one maximum  and no minimum in this domain. $f(x)=-x^3$ has neither max nor min in $x \in R$. $f(x)=-x^2$ has only one max and no min.

Comment: @GEdgar Yes. It exists.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In general, the result you want is false. You do need continuity of $f''$ at $y$ (although not necessarily on an interval containing $y$). Derivatives need not be continuous, although they do always have the intermediate value property, regardless. But that won't help here.

All we need to do is modify the usual example of a differentiable function whose derivative is not continuous:

$$f(x) = \begin{cases} x^2\sin(1/x), & x\ne 0 \\ 0, & x=0\end{cases}.$$
Note that $f'(0)=0$, but $f'$ oscillates (basically from $-1$ to $1$) as you approach $0$.

We can integrate this function, setting $F(x) = \int_0^x f(t)\,dt$. Then $F''=f'$ will of course have the same issues.

Alternatively, try
$$f(x) = \begin{cases} x^4\sin(1/x), & x\ne 0 \\ 0, & x=0\end{cases}.$$
What happens with $f''$?

Comment: Hi, so you are saying there is no weaker condition than the continuity of $f^{\prime\prime}$ at $y$ to ensure that the $f^{\prime\prime}(z) <0$ holds in an interval around $y$. Or are you saying that we cannot ensure  $f^{\prime\prime}(z) <0$ holds in an interval around $y$ no matter what condition we place on $f^{\prime\prime}$. Am I getting you correctly?

Comment: Ok it seems that you are referring to the second case.

Comment: No, first. A function that is continuous at $y$ and negative there is negative on an interval containing $y$.

Comment: I see. thank you.